# Character encoding garbled / changing when saving a file on server

Tags: utf-8

As a test, I paste the following text in a .php file on the server: 颜色分类
I then save, the file.
I close, and re-open the file, and then the text appears as : é¢œè‰²åˆ†ç±»
I then save the file again, without modifying the content, and re-open it again
The text then appears as:  Ã©Â¢Å“Ã¨â€°Â²Ã¥Ë†â€ Ã§Â±Â»

My headers are:  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
I checked my database is also on utf8_general_ci

However, could this really be those settings? The file is individually saved on the FTP without any server or database requests or anything.  Could this soley be due to the editor that is being used to save/upload the file? I use CoffeeCUP FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly likely that the editor is causing this. Have you tried saving it in an editor like Notepad++ (making sure the file is being saved with UTF-8 encoding) and uploading the file?

Comment: I'll try with Notepad++, and test it out, thank you for the suggestion.